# How to redirect a request through Oracle Service Bus

Tags: java, testing, redirect, response.redirect, oracle-service-bus

I have an ADF application (**adf_1**) and another one for authentication (**auth_1**).
When a user requests for a login through **adf_1**, the latter posts the data to **auth_1**, then **auth_1** will take from there and communicate with the user through authentication steps.

After authentication is finished, it redirects through *post* back to **adf_1**.

My application is under development and I can´t deploy to the prod/test server yet so I can't use it with **auth_1** for testing purposes.

I have an Oracle Service Bus (**osb_s**) server deployed under my control.

How can I use **osb_s** so that it would act similar to **auth_1** and receive and redirect *urls* to and from **adf_1**?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose the OSB proxy service either as an http/https service and make your ADF application post to this and do the required function.

Regards,
Sajeev